# html5 video sometimes loads and sometimes don't in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

I'm having a lot of problems with video html5 and google chrome.

I have this site on two different servers and chrome is showing the transition video aleatory.

http://mitoteweb.com/vivaldo/

I made some files to test the video the simplest way to check this problem and it isn't working.

I tried with mp4 h.264, ogv y webm video format and I'm having the same issues with all of them.

Here's the test files.

http://mitoteweb.com/vivaldo/chrome/prueba1.htm

When I load the page it shows the video but once I click on the second link it doesn't show any video unless I manually reload the page. And even with that, sometimes it doesn't happen.

Sorry, I couldn't include more links because this is my first post.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should better give us some code instead of links and describe where you are stuck in your code, it will be easier for us to help